# Convert PowerShell to Java

Tags: java, powershell

How can I convert this command to java code?

`powershell -command "$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes('%2'); [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes) | Out-File -append -FilePath '%2.base64' -Encoding ASCII -NoNewline"`

I am afraid if I convert to base64 will not be the same output.

Comment: I just want to make sure that I have the same output so what can I do to check that?

Comment: That reads to me like simple Base64 encoding, but without newlines. You can try your code and then [compare the output of both methods](https://serverfault.com/questions/5598/how-do-i-diff-two-text-files-in-windows-powershell).

Comment: @uiuk very easily: test your new java program by running both it, and the powershell script, against the same input and observe if you get the same output